# Android : how to initialize an activity in background before displaying it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an activity in which I display an image that is stored on a website.
I am using the following code to get it from its url and display the activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.ad_screen);

    AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>() 
    {
        /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
         * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            fetchAd();
            return 0; 
        }

        /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
         * the result from doInBackground() */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
        {
            displayAd();
        }
    };
    task.execute("");
}
```

That works very fine, but the behaviour is not the one I want : in this case, the activity is pushed on the screen (with a right to left animation) and then the AsyncTask begins. So the image is displayed on screen after a delay (which is normal).

But I would like to perform the request before the activity is pushed, so that the screen is displayed directly with its image without any delay.

Is there a way to have this behaviour ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the image in the previous activity, create a bitmap, then pass it as an extra in the intent that launches this activity.

Comment: Great ! I get the image in the parent, and set the Bitmap in the bundle of my new activity like this `bundle.putParcelable("data", ad);` ; then I just retrieve it with `Bitmap ad = (Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");`

Answer (score 2):

*Use AsyncTask to load images in previous activity, and display the images in the current activity.*

Answer (score 0):

You could in the "parent" activity, the one that starts the new activity, do the fetching of the content, store it either in memory or some sort of fast access persistence, and after that start the activity.

Same principle could be to introduce a "loader" activity which would show a loader, and prefetch the data, when all data received it would start the activity that should display the data.

Comment: Ok, in a static variable for example ?

Comment: I think this could work fine, but then I must not forget to pass the static variable containing the image to null when the activity finishes is lifecycle. So I prefer to use the bundle.putParcelable way.